# How to create geojson Polygons from Lines?

Tags: javascript, geojson, geometry-conversion, node-js

Given a series of overlapping lines (MultiLineString) in Geojson how can I create polygons for those portions that form an enclosed a space?

Sample data - https://gist.github.com/maphew/7bb77059574ea714977edae41e4b114c
[image: a grid of overlapping lines]

Operational environment is web browser and/or a server with Node.js. Desktop tools such as ArcGIS and QGIS are not available. Connection to a remote service API is acceptable but prefer to avoid. (Following principle of minimizing external dependencies.)

This is my first significant foray into javascript-land, some hand-holding may be needed. ;-)

#### What hasn't worked

Seeing [OGR DXF Closed Polyline Conversion](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131765/ogr-dxf-closed-polyline-conversion) I tried to filter the geojson through DXF to shapefile polygons using command line ogr2ogr (v2.2.0). Thinking if I could get it to work there I could replicate in [node-gdal](/questions/tagged/node-gdal). A polygon shapefile is created but it has no features. `-skipfailures` didn't help.

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58245/generate-polygons-from-a-set-of-intersecting-lines

Comment: I suppose you had better to use a ready solution to create polygons. For example PostGIS ST_Polygonize and ST_node or GRASS GIS.

Comment: There is a node module - [turf/linestring-to-polygon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/linestring-to-polygon) which might do the trick. If you want to do it all in the browser then You can probably implement the algorithm described [here](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-line-to-polygon/issues/4) using turf. ([docs](http://turfjs.org/docs/)).

Comment: Thanks @RoperMaps. Turf/linestring-to-polyon doesn't work, but in Turf I found another module, less than 1 month old, called [Turf/polygonize](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/pull/767). It reads like it should work, but doesn't. I filed [a bug](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/819), hopefully it gets fixed soon. :-)