# Converting linestring of the imported DXF to a closed polygon

Tags: polygon, line, convert, dxf, autocad

Is there a way to convert linestring of the imported DXF file to a closed polygon?

I am using QGIS 3.10.

Comment: Did you see this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/131836/63384?